# How to read data from Excel sheet using SQL statement in SSIS Package

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an Excel sheet which has the data starting from 17th row.

There are two columns:

```
A16 Name     B16 Value
A17    A     B17   1
A18    B     B18   2
A19    C     B19   3
```

How to write a SQL statement to read the data from these two columns from A17 to A19?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you choose Excel driver in your connection, you should be able to write a query like this: Select * FROM [Sheet1$]

Comment: Yes but I have to get the data from Specific rows.

Comment: based on row number? or any other criteria? you can use WHERE if there is a criteria but nor sure how you can do that to get specific row number.

Comment: In case you cannot find row number in Excel, you can push all data into a ADO record set and then get the specific row from ADO record set

Comment: Yes based on the row number from 17th row to 23rd row.

Comment: So, use ADO record set and look through data (using Script Task)